# Conditional operator, strange behavior

Tags: java, ternary-operator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o1;
    if (true)
        o1 = new Integer(5);
    else
        o1 = new Double(2.0);

    Object o2 = true ? new Integer(5) : new Double(2.0);

    System.out.println(o1);
    System.out.println(o2);
}
```

In the above sample code, by using the conditional operator (? :)  I can rewrite the above example in a single line. So, I think the result of **o1 & o2** must be the same. But, strangely, the result as below :

```
5
5.0
```

Could you guys please help me to point out why is this behaviour ?

**UPDATED** : 
The result will be the same with the following code:

```
Object o2 = true ? (Object) new Integer(5) : new Double(2.0);
```

Comment: I think it's odd that you get `Integer` in both cases, but only the format when printed is different.

Comment: Yes, both o1, o2 are Integer.

Comment: I tried it by doing instanceof and the second result is false..   `o1 instanceof Integer` results true  while `o2 instanceOf Integer` result s false.. so it means that o2 is not an Integer

Comment: This is very strange behavior indeed. o2 is actually a double.

Comment: its defiantly a Double. I printed the classname. see my answer on autoboxing

Comment: I checked both o1, o2 are Integer as well ( instanceof Integer ), JDK is : 1.7.0.65

Comment: @JohnKugelman : yep, it's duplicate with the linked question. Thanks. :) Before casting o2 to Object, it actually is an Integer.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, it's embarrassing that it is my mistake that I was not really using Java 1.8 to compile, I am sorry and I now delete my comment above.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a side effect of Autoboxing. The ? operator attempts to determine which is the base type that can be applied to Object. It sees Double on the right, and Integer, which can be autoboxed to Double as well.

Maybe it does this because Integer can be boxed to Double, but Double can not be boxed to Integer?

Note that this produces the same result...

```
Object o2 = true ? 5 : new Double(2.0);
```

Comment: I don't get it. How can `new Integer(5)` be autoboxed to `Double`? It is already an Object type.

Comment: its being unboxed and reboxed. I'm not say I agree with it, but thats defiantly what is happening. System.out.println(o2.getClass()); shows you it's a Double and boxing is the only way Integer(5) could have been transformed to the Double

Comment: @Thilo It isn't. Binary numeric promotion is applied.

Comment: It is Autoboxing it as Double(Integer(5))

Comment: I'm worry if I use Long and Float, it return the same result, but Float not cover Long type